# Typescript: Only one of several interfaces

Tags: typescript, types, interface, union

Is it possible to declare a type which defines that only one of several interfaces is valid?

For example:

```
interface Bar {
    properties: Record<string,any>
    construct?: () => void
    convert?: () => void
}

interface Foo {
    type?: string
    optional?: boolean
}

type FooBar = Bar | Foo;


//should not work
({
    properties: {},
    type: 'number'
} as FooBar);

//should not work
({
    convert: () => {},
    type: 'number'
} as FooBar);

//should work
({
    type: 'number',
    optional: true
} as FooBar);

//should work
({
    properties: {},
    convert: () => {}
} as FooBar);
```

I want to achieve when the property: 'properties' is defined that only the optional properties of the interface 'Bar' can be added. And, when the property: 'properties' is not defined only the properties of the interface 'Foo' can be used.
I tried it with Union but then its also possible to mix the interfaces.

How can I solve the problem and is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that is the only way to do this is to use [Discriminated Unions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#discriminated-unions). Like so:

```
interface Foo {
    type: "foo";
    foo: number;
}

interface Bar {
    type: "bar";
    bar: string;
}

type FooBar = Foo | Bar;

let bar: FooBar = {
    type: "bar",
    foo: 42 // error
}
```

[Playground link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4ChkHJgCeADhAFzIBEMm1A3PoXelSAK4C2ARtEwF9cuUJFiIUAIThQczAiXJVqPGY3nJVUKgGcwUUAHNBwxSgzppsgLxpMyAD7IrTXABsIYTTKoWryWzxCIjJKGi1qABoNVioAFgAmZAB6ZORoKHQoXCEgA)